# Prove that $(a+b)^4\ge8ab(a^2+b^2)$ for $a,b\ge 0$.

Tags: inequality

As in the title. Prove that for nonnegative $a$ and $b$ the following inequality holds:
$$(a+b)^4\ge8ab(a^2+b^2).$$
Note that I'm **not** looking for a complete solution, but only for some **hints**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: $$(a+b)^4-(a-b)^4 = 8ab(a^2+b^2)$$

Comment: And... now it's completely trivial. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A hint could be this one

$$(a + b)^4 = (a+b)^2(a+b)^2 = (a^2 + b^2)(a+b)^2 + 2ab(a^2 + b^2) + 4a^2b^2$$

Or similar manipulations!

Comment: the hint doesn't help as the $RHS \geq 4ab(a^2+b^2) + 2ab(a^2+b^2) + 4a^2b^2 = 6ab(a^2+b^2) + 4a^2b^2$